# Help with SQLite query to generate new table based on lookups

Tags: sqlite

Sorry, I can't think of a more specific title.

SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cfed3/1/0

I have a BaseData table

| Name | ParamId | NumericValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 202 | 30 |
| B | 203 | 69 |
| O | 203 | 50 |
| A | 203 | 70 |
| I | 204 | 2 |
| B | 204 | 1 |
| O | 204 | 1 |
| A | 204 | 1 |
| J | 205 | 2 |
| F | 205 | 1 |

- Where ParamId = 204 or 205, the NumericValue is a "ClusterNumber".
- Where ParamId = 202, the NumericValue is a "LowerThreshold".
- Where ParamId = 203, the NumericValue is an "UpperThreshold".

Now we need to create a cluster table where the ClusterNumber comes from the BaseData table where ParamId = 204 or 205, and we default the lower and upper threshold to 0 and 100:

| ClusterNumber | LowerThreshold | UpperThreshold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 100 |
| 2 | 0 | 100 |

Now we update the Lower and Upper thresholds. Take for example, the LowerThreshold (ParamId = 202), there is only one row, and it's name is A. To determine the ClusterNumber, we look for where A is where ParamId = 204 or 205, we see that it is ClusterNumber = 1. Thus, ClusterNumber 1 has LowerThreshold 30.

If there are multiple numbers for lower/upper thresholds, then the last one wins.
We should end up with this table:

| ClusterNumber | LowerThreshold | UpperThreshold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 70 |
| 2 | 0 | 100 |

I can't work out how to set the Lower and Upper thresholds. You can see my code here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cfed3/1/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create a Cluster table, you can get your desired result in a single query:

```
with Clusters as (
  select Name, NumericValue as ClusterNumber from BaseData
     where BaseData.ParamId in (204,205)
),
lowers as (
  select Clusters.ClusterNumber, Basedata.NumericValue 
  from Basedata join Clusters on Basedata.Name=Clusters.Name 
  where ParamId=202 
  group by ClusterNumber
  order by Basedata.rowid desc
 ),
uppers as (
  select Clusters.ClusterNumber, Basedata.NumericValue 
  from Basedata join Clusters on Basedata.Name=Clusters.Name 
  where ParamId=203 
  group by ClusterNumber
  order by Basedata.rowid desc
 )
select distinct ClusterNumber, 
       coalesce((select lowers.NumericValue from lowers where lowers.ClusterNumber=Clusters.ClusterNumber),0) as LowerThreshold, 
       coalesce((select uppers.NumericValue from uppers where uppers.ClusterNumber=Clusters.ClusterNumber),100) as UpperThreshold 
from Clusters
order by ClusterNumber;
```

I used some CTE's for clarity.
You can use it as a view or store it into a table.
Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cfed3/48